# How to set Plain Email Sender Name in Django?

Tags: django, sendmail, registration

How to set plain email sender name in Django? A sender name is usually email address preset in settings.py.

In my settings,

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'rest.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.test.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'customer@test.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = base64.b64decode('xxxxxxxxxx')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I use django registration/django celery.

When I receive some emails from server using web client, Sender Name is just email address, or mail server username.

Can anyone suggest me how to set plain sender name in django?

Comment: Basically do `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'No-Reply <noreply@host.com>'` if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @sagarchalise It works! thanks a lot. I will answer my question with your answer to close it.

Answer (score 3):

as @sagarchalise comment it, I just do

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Customer Center <noreply@host.com>'
```

previously, I did

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ADMINS[0][1]
```

which is just email address.

thanks again, @sagarchalise.